# WDM: autologin after boot

Tags: x11, lxde, display-manager

I am using `Debian Wheezy` with `wdm` and `LXDE`. I would like to have my user to be logged into LXDE automatically after computer start. I know this is possible with other display managers, such as `gdm`.

Is there some way to configure this in `wdm`? If not in `wdm`, is there some workaround to do it with some script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article looks like it will do exactly what you're looking for

http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/06/auto-login-auto-load-lxde/

Comment: so this solution completely bypasses `wdm` ? I wonder what will happen once I log out of `LXDE`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the reprecussions might be, there is another option that I just found online, it might be what you want, but you have to hit enter twice during login

Comment: "One possible option would be WDM, which is a modified version of XDM. WDM doesn't actually support autologin but you can set the default user and default password in /etc/X11/wdm/wdm-config. Now, when Debian boots to WDM you only need to press Enter twice (first to activate the default user and second time to activate the default password) to login to your default window manager (WDM also gives you an automatically updated list of all installed window managers / desktop environments). " -- http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/auto-login-normal-user-debian-276575/